# Get distance to surface with ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I've begun experimenting with ARKit, and I have ran into an issue. I can't find a tutorial which shows how to place an object on the nearest surface.

Let's say I am using a `.scn` file that contains a flat object. I know how to place that where the camera is, but how would I get the distance to the nearest surface.

[image: Such as in this image, where it detects how far away the table is.]

Sorry if this sounds like a code-request, but I am not sure where to start, any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: If you're still interested in a tutorial, and for future people who check this question, there are 2 that really helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfAadJNX3Tc as well as this 4 part tutorial: https://blog.markdaws.net/apple-arkit-by-example-ef1c8578fb59. 

They both cover material that is essential in learning ARKit and are two different ways of placing objects and such.

Comment: Hi anybody tried placing a focus square image like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [hitTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2875718-hittest) that might return you results that contains informations such as distance and transform: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arhittestresult

```
for result in sceneView.hitTest(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), types: [.existingPlaneUsingExtent, .featurePoint]) {
  print(result.distance, result.worldTransform)
}
```